# How do determine if an object is of a certain type?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

If you run the codes below and your spreadsheet has a date column, the date format looks like this on the client page: Thu May 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)

I want to format the date to something like this: May 23, 2013

I figure you could do that by changing the line

```
<td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
```

to

```
<td><?= Utilities.formatDate(new Date(data[i][j]), "GMT-5", "MMM dd, yyyy")data[i][j] ?></td>
```

...but the problem is that not every data in the array is a date object. How do I check if an object in an array is of a certain type? I would like to determine if the current object is a date object before applying the formatDate function.

*Code.gs*

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate();
}

function getData() {
  return SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('123abc')
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues();
}
```

*index.html*

```
<? var data = getData(); ?>
<table>
  <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
    <tr>
      <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
        <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
      <? } ?>
    </tr>
  <? } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [many questions and answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20get%20object%20type) about getting an object's type in javascript. Make sure you read them all!

Here's a simple change that matches the style of your existing code. Put the formatter function in `Code.gs`, and have the templated html utilize it on each 'cell' as the table is built.

#### Code.gs

... everything you have plus this:

```
function formatIfDate(obj) {
  if (obj.constructor.name == 'Date')
    return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(obj), "GMT-5", "MMM dd, yyyy")
  else 
    return obj
};
```

#### index.html

Change

```
<td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
```

to

```
<td><?= formatIfDate(data[i][j]) ?></td>
```

Comment: Thanks for response, it works! Also the first question/answer in the link you posted is very informative.